# Laravel - requests validation loose errors on redirect

Tags: php, laravel, session, redirect

I have a custom request file in `http/requests` which handles validation.

If validation does not pass, by default it should **redirect** back with `$errors` in the view (which are generated by `\Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class`) and I see that the errors are in the session while debuging, but after this request with code `302` finishes and `200` request is generated, errors in the session are lost.

What might cause this issue? Thanks

Code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;
<..>
class AnswerQuestionnaireRequest extends FormRequest
{
    private $questionRepository;

    /**
     * AnswerQuestionnaireRequest constructor.
     */
    public function __construct(QuestionRepository $qs)
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->questionRepository = $qs;
    }

    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        $rules = [];
        foreach ($this->questionRepository->getAll() as $question){
            $index = "question-" . $question->id;
            $rules[$index] = "required|in:1,2";
        }

        return $rules;

    }

    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'question-1.required' => __("Incorrect value"),
            'question-2.required'  => __("Incorrect value"),
        ];
    }

}


class QuestionnairesController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct(QuestionnairesService $questionnairesService, QuestionRepository $questionRepository)
    {
        $this->questionnairesService = $questionnairesService;
        $this->questionRepository = $questionRepository;
    }

    public function show(Request $request){
        $questions = $this->questionRepository->getAll();
        return view("client/questionnaire", compact("questions"));
    }

    public function store(AnswerQuestionnaireRequest $request){
        var_dump($request);
    }
```

EDIT:
Checking with Xdebug you can see, that the validation worked, but it's only for the request, that return code 302 and redirects back. https://gyazo.com/231c83910f6e57748e1b705ade74e383
And when the request 200 is loading, this error bag is already empty there.

Comment: Can you show us your controller?

Comment: we need to see your code to fix your problem

Comment: added the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrapping everything in routes/web.php to "Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {" fixed the issue.

I thought that everything in web.php file is already assigned to "WEB" middleware...

Answer (score 1):

In your controller try this, assuming the function is create

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
public function create(Request $request){
    $this->validate($request,[
    'field'=>'required|present',
    'another_field'=>'required|present',
    ]);
   Post::create($request);
}
```

Do note that the $this->validate(), if there is a validation error it is automatically redirected back to the previous url with the error messages sent.
**Blade**
You can then check for errors this way

```
@if($errors->has('fieldName'))
    <small class="text-danger form-text">{{$errors->first('fieldName')}}</small>
@endif
```

Comment: My validation is in the http/requests and therefore I don't have $this->validate()